# check for same range in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-update

I wanted to check if for one particular student my column (`Amount`) contains a value less than 10, and if yes, then check if for the same student my column (`Amount`) is also greater than 10 and update the column `new` accordingly in PostgreSQL.

MY table:

[image: x]

Tried this way but not working

```
update table t1 set "New"='pass'
where cast("Amount" as numeric) <= 10 and cast("Amount" as numeric) > 10
```

The output I'm expecting:

[image: y]

Comment: That `WHERE` condition is always `FALSE`. Please describe what you want to do in more detail. Use short sentences.

Comment: Kindly check the updated image

Comment: if i found amount for one student is less than 10 and greater than 10 also then i will update my column

Comment: first i wanted to check amount for one student is less than 10 if yes then i will check amount for same student  greater than 10  if both conditions satisfied then update

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to self-join the table with an aggregate subquery, and then do a conditional assignment in the outer query:

```
update t1
set new = case when min_amount <= 10 and max_amount > 10 then 'pass' else 'not pass' end
from (
    select name, min(amount::numeric) min_amount, max(amount::numeric) max_amount
    from t1 
    group by name 
) t2
where t1.name = t2.name
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0cf54bb74876704086d16bb316bd23a4)**:

```
name  | amount | new     
:---- | :----- | :-------
Harry | 3      | pass    
Harry | 50     | pass    
Ron   | 5      | not pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the trick:

```
UPDATE atable AS t1
SET "New" = EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM atable t2
                    WHERE t2."Name" = t1."Name"
                      AND t2."Amount" <= 10)
            AND
            EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM atable t2
                    WHERE t2."Name" = t1."Name"
                      AND t2."Amount" > 10);
```